# Why does my code do not run the switch statement? (Linked List)

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am a beginner and still learning how to use a switch statement. My professor asked us to make a linked list using a switch statement. I don't really know why the switch statement is not working as intended to be. Hoping someone can help me.

## OUTPUT

The output of the program should look like this

```
Menu
[1] Inserting value in the link
[2] Deleting value in the link
[3] Exit

Enter your choice: (Input)

Inserting/Deleting a value at
[a] Beginning
[b] Middle
[c] End
[d] Exit

Enter your choice: (Input)

Input the value to be inserted/deleted: (Input)

The values in the link are: (Output)
```

### CODE

Here is the code that I'm working with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define getch() _getch()
using namespace std;

struct dlinklist
{
    struct dlinklist* left;
    int data;
    struct dlinklist* right;
};
typedef struct dlinklist node;
node* start = NULL;

node* getnode()
{
    node* newnode;
    newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    cout << "\n Input the value to be inserted: ";
    cin >> newnode->data;

    newnode->left = NULL;
    newnode->right = NULL;
    return newnode;
}
int menu()
{
    char ah;
    int ch;
    cout << "\n----------------------------------";
    cout << "\nMenu";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------";
    cout << "\n[1] Inserting value in the link";
    cout << "\n[2] Deleting value in the link";
    cout << "\n[3] Exit";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------";
    cout << "\n\n Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> ch;

    if (ch == 1)
    {
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n    Inserting a value at:";
        cout << "\n[a] The Beginning of the list";
        cout << "\n[b] The middle of the list";
        cout << "\n[c] The end of the list";
        cout << "\n[d] Exit";
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n\n Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> ah;
    }
    else if (ch == 2)
    {
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n    Deleting a value at:";
        cout << "\n[a] The Beginning of the list";
        cout << "\n[b] The middle of the list";
        cout << "\n[c] The end of the list";
        cout << "\n[d] Exit";
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n\n Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> ah;
    }
    else if (ch == 3)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void insert_beg()
{
//code
}

void insert_end()
{
//code
}

void insert_mid()
{
//code
}

void delete_beg()
{
//code
}

void delete_end()
{
//code
}

void delete_mid()
{
//code
}

void main(void)
{
    int ch = menu();
    char ah;
    while(1)
    {
        ah = menu();
        switch(ah)
        {
        case 'A': case 'a':
            if (ch == 1)
            {
                insert_beg();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                delete_beg();
                break;
            }
        case 'B': case 'b':
            if (ch == 1)
            {
                insert_mid();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                delete_mid();
                break;
            }
        case 'C': case 'c':
            if (ch == 1)
            {
                insert_end();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                delete_end();
                break;
            }
        case 'D': case 'd':
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return;

}
```

Comment: Don't tag C++ code with the C tag unless you're particularly fond of downvotes.  Your code is clearly C++; do not add the C tag too.

Comment: Your menu function doesn't return a value, so that calling code can't use it.

Comment: Also, your menu function can only return one value, but you seem to be expecting to receive two. (Do you believe there is a connection between the `ah` and `ch` variables in `menu` and the ones in `main`?)

Comment: FYI, in C++ you don't need to use `typedef` with `struct`.  You can refer to the struct by the tag name.  In your case, you can instantiate a node with `dlinklist * node = new dlinklist;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menu` does not return any value.

You probably want to do this:

```
int menu()
{
    char ah;
    int ch;
    cout << "\n----------------------------------";
    cout << "\nMenu";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------";
    cout << "\n[1] Inserting value in the link";
    cout << "\n[2] Deleting value in the link";
    cout << "\n[3] Exit";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------";
    cout << "\n\n Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> ch;

    if (ch == 1)
    {
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n    Inserting a value at:";
        cout << "\n[a] The Beginning of the list";
        cout << "\n[b] The middle of the list";
        cout << "\n[c] The end of the list";
        cout << "\n[d] Exit";
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n\n Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> ah;

        return ah; // return statement
    }
    else if (ch == 2)
    {
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n    Deleting a value at:";
        cout << "\n[a] The Beginning of the list";
        cout << "\n[b] The middle of the list";
        cout << "\n[c] The end of the list";
        cout << "\n[d] Exit";
        cout << "\n----------------------------------";
        cout << "\n\n Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> ah;

        return ah; // return statement
    }
    else if (ch == 3)
    {
        // exit(0); don't write this here, call the exit inside main()

        return 3; // 3 or anything, you can return other values if you want
    }
}
```

And in `main`:

```
int ch = menu();
if (ch == 3) exit(0);
```

Don't forget about *return statements* when writing functions.

**Important note:** Do not use ambiguous names for variables/functions/classes etc. For example, what does `ah` or `ch` really mean? How people reading your cryptic code are supposed to know that? Always try to use **descriptive** names.

Comment: `case 'A': case 'a':` is useful when you want `a` and `A` to do the same thing - which is likely the case here.

Comment: I think you're wrong. The purpose is to make user input case insensitive

Comment: @tony_merguez Thanks for mentioning that. I fixed it.

Comment: @interjay Yes, you're right. I somehow forgot about that.

Comment: This is part of the issue, but still OP thinks that variables in `menu()` and `main()` are somehow shared because they have the same name. They need both `ch` and `ah`  set in `main()` with current code.

Comment: You could use the `switch` statement.  The `switch` statement is a good candidate when using menus.  You may want to refactor submenus to separate functions.